# Deployment Toolkit for Java applets: how to avoid the redirect when no JVM is installed

Tags: java, javascript, applet, jnlp, java-deployment-toolkit

I have created an applet; it is deployed using the [Deployment Toolkit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/depltoolkit_index.html) as below (the URLs are fake):

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
             src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
var attributes = {
        code:'br.com.brandizzi.adam.applet.MyApplet.class',
        archive:'http://adam.brandizzi.com.br/html/applet.jar',
        width : 50,
        height : 1
    };
    var parameters = {
        fontSize : 1,
    };
    var version = '1.6';
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
</script>
```

It works well. Luckily, however, I reached my site through a machine without JVM and it was always redirected to http://www.java.com - as [the documentation states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/runAppletFunction.html):

> If the client does not have the required minimum version of the JRE software, the Deployment Toolkit script redirects the browser to http://www.java.com to allow users to download the latest JRE software. On some platforms, users might be redirected before they can view the web page containing the applet.

Is there a way to avoid this redirect? The page can work great without JVM, the applet is just a little improvement. Anyway, our users can become very confused with this redirect and they not even have permissions to install JVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of using the Deployment Toolkit is that it prompts the user to install a JVM if they don't have one, so that your applet can run.  If you don't want them to be prompted, then simply don't use the Deployment Toolkit.

If they have a suitable JVM installed already then your applet will run.  If not, the remainder of the page should load normally.

Comment: That is fair but it is not smart to just redirect the user to another page without any information. Also, I was trying to avoid the <applet> tag but it is considered deprecated. Anyway, I am surprised that the Deployment Toolkit does not have such a simple option...

Comment: @brandizzi The option is "don't use the Toolkit in the first place". Also, it's a single JS file, it should be possible to monkeypatch it.

Comment: The Deployment Toolkit isn't doing anything magic.  The commented code is available at http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.txt, so if you want to change the behaviour, save a copy to your website, for example http://adam.brandizzi.com.br/html/myDeployJava.js, change the script tag in your html to point to that instead of https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js and change the behaviour.  However, if you look at what deployJava.js does, it actually inserts an <applet> tag if the user has a JVM installed, so it isn't "avoiding the <applet> tag".

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look at the deployJava.js script and the runApplet function is says:

> ```
>      /**
>      * Ensures that an appropriate JRE is installed and then runs an applet.
>      * minimumVersion is of the form #[.#[.#[_#]]], and is the minimum
>      * JRE version necessary to run this applet.  minimumVersion is optional,
>      * defaulting to the value "1.1" (which matches any JRE).
>      * If an equal or greater JRE is detected, runApplet() will call
>      * writeAppletTag(attributes, parameters) to output the applet tag,
>      * otherwise it will call installJRE(minimumVersion + '+').
> ```

So if you make the call like this

```
deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, null);
```

or like this

```
deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, 'undefined');
```

or like this

```
deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.1');
```

it will only check if Java is installed *at all*, and only then redirect to java.com for installation. And since you have an applet, you do need Java :)

Alternatively you can call **deployJava.writeAppletTag(attributes, parameters)** directy:

> ```
>     /**
>      * Outputs an applet tag with the specified attributes and parameters, where
>      * both attributes and parameters are associative arrays.  Each key/value
>      * pair in attributes becomes an attribute of the applet tag itself, while
>      * key/value pairs in parameters become <PARAM> tags.  No version checking
>      * or other special behaviors are performed; the tag is simply written to
>      * the page using document.writeln().
>      *
>      * As document.writeln() is generally only safe to use while the page is
>      * being rendered, you should never call this function after the page
>      * has been completed.
>      */
> ```

Comment: "since you have an applet, you do need Java" is not true because he wrote: "the page can work great without JVM, the applet is just a little improvement".

Comment: Where is the full version? I only see a minimized version

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getJREs` function from [deployJava.js](http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.txt).